# Google Cloud Functions - e-mail script - CORS error

Tags: python, http, post, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a function that receives data through POST request and sends an email with that data.
When i try to call my function from a different domain i get the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my function' from origin 'chrome-search://local-ntp' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I followed the instructions on the cloud documentation and added the following to the top of my code:

```
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
}
return ('', 204, headers)
```

The error was solved but the rest of my code doesn't run after the return statement. How can i insert the headers and then continue running my script?

The whole code looks like that:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from google.cloud import storage
import requests

def teste_email(request):

    headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    }
    return ('', 204, headers)


    # Pega as variáveis passadas no request
    request_json = request.get_json()
    nome_projeto = request_json['nome_projeto']
    logo_ic = request_json['logo_ic']
    logo_aplicacao = request_json['logo_aplicacao']
    title = request_json['title']
    link = request_json['link']
    descricao = request_json['descricao']
    base = request_json['base']

    # Lê o arquivo do template armazenado no cloud storage e o atribui a uma variável
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('templates_email_icherry')
    blob = bucket.get_blob("template-1.txt")
    downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
    template = downloaded_blob.decode("utf-8")

    # Substitui as variáveis no template pelos valores passados na chamada
    template = template.replace("{title}", title)
    template = template.replace("{logo_ic}", logo_ic)
    template = template.replace("{logo_aplicacao}", logo_aplicacao)
    template = template.replace("{descricao}", descricao)
    template = template.replace("{link}", link)
    template = template.replace("{nome_projeto}", nome_projeto)
    template = template.replace("{base}", base)

    # Variáveis para o envio do e-mail
    email = 'email'
    password = 'password'
    send_to_email = 'email'
    subject = 'Assunto do email'
    messagePlain = 'Message Plain'

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText (messagePlain, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText (template, 'html'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: `return` after your other code executes, not before.

Comment: I tried that too, it gives me the same error

Comment: The only way i could make the error disappear is with the code like that

Comment: This problem is going to be hard to help you without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited the question so the code is more detailed

Comment: You need to show exactly how everything is put together. This includes the URLs. Adding headers to `teste_email` does not solve the problem as the CORS error is caused by attempting to call an endpoint. This means the endpoint never gets to return headers as the call does not happen. This error is caused by loading a page from one domain and attempting to make an HTTP request to a different domain - this is what a cross origin means. You don't show these pieces.

Comment: CORS is enforced by the browser. This is a security feature and not something your code does other than to tell the browser that cross-origin requests are OK. That must be done via headers from origin server (the server serving the page that is making the request). Using tools such as `curl` help you create precise requests and see the response headers.

Comment: I edited your question to remove any sensitive information since it may potentially have some privacy concerns. Please remember not to include any personal information in your code or in your next question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have to put the [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?#return) statement at the end of the call. This is because return is an instruction that stops the execution of the current function call and returns the value associated.

Therefore, if you want your code to execute AND return the CORS headers, it must be the last call of your function. This is the resulting code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from google.cloud import storage
import requests

def teste_email(request):

    # Pega as variáveis passadas no request
    request_json = request.get_json()
    nome_projeto = request_json['nome_projeto']
    logo_ic = request_json['logo_ic']
    logo_aplicacao = request_json['logo_aplicacao']
    title = request_json['title']
    link = request_json['link']
    descricao = request_json['descricao']
    base = request_json['base']

    # Lê o arquivo do template armazenado no cloud storage e o atribui a uma variável
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('templates_email_icherry')
    blob = bucket.get_blob("template-1.txt")
    downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
    template = downloaded_blob.decode("utf-8")

    # Substitui as variáveis no template pelos valores passados na chamada
    template = template.replace("{title}", title)
    template = template.replace("{logo_ic}", logo_ic)
    template = template.replace("{logo_aplicacao}", logo_aplicacao)
    template = template.replace("{descricao}", descricao)
    template = template.replace("{link}", link)
    template = template.replace("{nome_projeto}", nome_projeto)
    template = template.replace("{base}", base)

    # Variáveis para o envio do e-mail
    email = 'email'
    password = 'password'
    send_to_email = 'email'
    subject = 'Assunto do email'
    messagePlain = 'Message Plain'

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText (messagePlain, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText (template, 'html'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()

    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    }
    return ('', 204, headers)
```